# JTextPane in JToggleButton, ignore mouse events?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jtogglebutton

Hi guys
I am in a strange situation: there is a **JToggleButton** with a **JTextPane** as a child component. If I click on the JTextPane, the relative button's events don't go in action (because he understands that i want to click on the JTextPane, which i'd like to set "unclickable").
How could i solve this? :)

Comment: Do you want the action to be performed when clicking on the JTextPane or not? this is not so clear from your question...

Comment: sorry, my english is not very good :) yes, i want the togglebutton's action to be performed when i click on the textpane... the textpane must be just a view-component, like a simple label, without gaining any focus or clicks

Comment: Why won't you simply use `setText()` on the button?

Comment: because it's not so simple: this togglebutton is like a little container with 2 labels and 2 textpanes

Comment: You may be able to do it with addFocusListener...

Comment: I don't understand how a toggle button can contain 2 labels and text panes. Strange design. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. Maybe we can suggest something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like this

```
aJToggleButton tButton=new aJToggleButton();//contains JTextPane
tButton.getTextPane().addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  ((aJToggleButton )((JTextPane)e.getSource()).getParent()).setSelected(true);
}
```

Anyway, it would be more helpful to see the component docs... Still I guess, the snippet touches the conception

Good luck